# .dockerignore fails to include files in subdirectories with !**/*.extension pattern

Tags: docker

I'm having trouble with the `.dockerignore` file. This is my project structure:

```
file.sh
file.js
file.go
file.py
subdir/
    file2.go
    file2.py
.dockerignore
Dockerfile
```

According to the [`.dockerignore` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file):

> (...) you may want to specify which files to include in the context, rather than which to exclude. To achieve this, specify * as the first pattern, followed by one or more ! exception patterns.

And:

> Lines starting with ! (exclamation mark) can be used to make exceptions to exclusions.

Finally:

> Docker also supports a special wildcard string ** that matches any number of directories (including zero). For example, **/*.go will exclude all files that end with .go that are found in all directories, including the root of the build context.

Based on that, this is my `.dockerignore` file:

```
# ignore everything
*

# whitelist
# ---------

# python files
!**/*.py
```

When I build and run the container and inspect the files, I get this:

```
file.py
```

The `subdir` directory is missing, `subdir/file2.py`should be included. It works if I add `!subdir/**/.py` to my `.dockerignore`, but the idea is to include any `.py` file in any subdirectory.

This is the file structure that should be present in the container:

```
file.py
subdir/
    file2.py
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a few issues that mention this exact problem, like these:

[Exception patterns in .dockerignore do not support wildcard directories](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30018)
[dockerignore does not respect the "special wildcard **"](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21433#issuecomment-222669110) (comment)

And it seems like it's not gonna be fixed any time soon :(