# How do I exclude everything except .go files in .dockerignore?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerignore

So, I have a dummy project, which file structure looks like this:

```
docker-magic
├── Dockerfile
├── .dockerignore
├── just_a_file
├── src
│   ├── folder_one
│   │   ├── main.go
│   │   └── what_again.sh
│   ├── folder_two
│   │   └── what.kts
│   └── level_one.go
└── top_level.go
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest as builder

WORKDIR /workdir

COPY ./ ./

RUN find . -type f

ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "wow"]
```

I build this image with a `docker build . -t docker-magic:test --no-cache` command to avoid caching results.

The idea is simple - I copy all of the files from `docker-magic` folder into my image and then list all of them via `find . -type f`.

Also I want to ignore some of the files. I do that with a `.dockerignore` file. According to the [official Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file):

> The placement of ! exception rules influences the behavior: the last line of the .dockerignore that matches a particular file determines whether it is included or excluded.

Let's consider following contents of `.dockerignore`:

```
**/*.go
```

It should exclude all the .go files. And it does! I get following contents from find:

```
./.dockerignore
./src/folder_one/what_again.sh
./src/folder_two/what.kts
./just_a_file
./Dockerfile
```

Next, let's ignore everything. `.dockerignore` is now:

```
**/*
```

And, as expected, I get empty output from find.

Now it gets difficult. I want to ignore all the files except .go files. According to the docs, it would be the following:

```
**/*

!**/*.go
```

But I get the following output from find:

```
./top_level.go
```

Which is obviously not what is expected, because other .go files, as we have seen, also match this pattern. How do I get the result I wanted - copying only .go files to my image?

**EDIT:** my Docker version is `20.10.5, build 55c4c88`.

Comment: Seems like there is still a limitation in the dockerignore. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594502/dockerignore-fails-to-include-files-in-subdirectories-with-extension-patt)

Comment: There is already a question related to the topic: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56594502/dockerignore-fails-to-include-files-in-subdirectories-with-extension-patt).